# Extract text Webpack plugin compile error

Tags: javascript, webpack, extract-text-plugin, extracttextwebpackplugin

I'm using `"webpack": "^3.1.0"` and  `"extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^1.0.1"`

Trying to compile sass and I get the following error: `Error: "extract-text-webpack-plugin" loader is used without the corresponding plugin, refer to https://github.com/webpack/extract-text-webpack-plugin for the usage example`

I have used this as per the documents provided - don't understand why I'm getting webpack build errors.

Here is my webpack file:

```
const debug = process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production";
const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  context: path.join(__dirname, "src"),
  devtool: debug ? "inline-sourcemap" : null,
  entry: ['./js/client.js', './styles/base.scss'],
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        query: {
          presets: ['react', 'es2015', 'stage-0'],
          plugins: ['react-html-attrs', 'transform-class-properties', 'transform-decorators-legacy'],
        }
      }, 
      { 
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
          fallback: 'style-loader',
          //resolve-url-loader may be chained before sass-loader if necessary
          use: ['css-loader', 'sass-loader']
        })
      }
    ]
  },
  output: {
    path: __dirname + "/src/",
    filename: "client.min.js"
  },
  plugins: debug ? [] : [
    new webpack.optimize.DedupePlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({ mangle: false, sourcemap: false }),
    new ExtractTextPlugin('main.css')
  ],
};
```

Comment: If debug is true you would not use the ExtractTextPlugin

Comment: @jantimon Can you please explain your comment? I don't quite understand.

Comment: `plugins: debug ? [] :` means that you won't use any plugins if debug is not true

Comment: @jantimon Ok so I need to remove this? I'm unsure how debug is affecting this as well

Answer (score 0):

You need to include something to tell where webpack to look, for example:

```
 {
    test: /(\.css|\.scss|\.sass)$/,
    include: path.join(__dirname, "../src"), // Include or exclude node modules
    use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
      fallback: "style-loader",
      use: ["css-loader", "sass-loader"],
    }),
 },
```

Comment: not sure why you have `'./styles/base.scss'` there..., the include or exclude is to exclusively tell the loader where to look for your styes. The entry is for where you want webpack to look to start bundling.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my **webpack.config.babel.js** file I hope this will helps you.

```
    import HtmlWebpackPlugin from 'html-webpack-plugin';
    import ExtractTextPlugin,{extract} from 'extract-text-webpack-plugin';
    import {resolve,join} from 'path';
    // import webpack from 'webpack';

    // var isProd = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'; //return true or false
    // var cssDev = [ "style-loader", "css-loader", "sass-loader" ];
    // var cssProd = extract({
    //     fallback: "style-loader",
    //     use: [ "css-loader", "sass-loader"],
    //     publicPath:'/dist'  
    // });
    // var cssConf = isProd ? cssProd : cssDev;


    module.exports = {
        entry: {
            app:'./src/app.js',
        },
        output: {
            path: join(__dirname, "dist"),
            filename : '[name].bundle.js' 
        },
        module: {
            rules:[
                {
                    test: /\.scss$/,
                    exclude: /node_modules/,
                    use: extract({
                        fallback: "style-loader",
                        use: [ "css-loader", "sass-loader"],
                        publicPath:'/dist'  
                    })
                },
                {
                    test: /\.js$/,
                    exclude: /node_modules/,
                    loader: "babel-loader"
                },
                {
                    test: /\.(png|jpg|gif)$/,
                    use:"file-loader",
                }
            ]
        },
        devServer:{
            contentBase: join(__dirname, "dist"),
            compress: true,
            port: 9000,
            stats:'errors-only',
        },
        plugins: [
            new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
                title: 'Webpack starter project',
                template: './src/index.html',
                hash:true,
                excludeChunks: ['contact'],
                minify:{
                    collapseWhitespace: true,
                    minifyCSS: true,
                    minifyJS:true,
                }
            }),
            new ExtractTextPlugin({
                filename: "app.css",
                // disable: !isProd,
                disable: false,            
                allChunks: true
            }),
            // new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
            // new webpack.NamedModulesPlugin(),
        ]
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

- you have to change the version of Extract Text Plugin
- Instead of *new ExtractTextPlugin('main.css')* use  **new 
  ExtractTextPlugin({ filename: "main.css"})**